# Cannot Install OS from Bootable FAT32 Drive

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, iso-image

I have put an Ubuntu 18.04.4 disc image on a JetFlash Transcend 1100 8 GB which is formatted as FAT32 with the intent to install it on an ASUS F555L laptop. This USB drive is recognized by the BIOS and appears in the boot priority list. However, setting it to the primary boot device has no discernible effect. On restart, the laptop boots to the Windows OS currently on the hard drive. Moreover, attempting to manually boot from it in the BIOS causes a window to flash up onto the screen for a fraction of a second; the screen goes black, and then it boots the Windows system anyway. Attempting the manual boot afterwards only flashes the screen black for an even briefer interval and nothing happens.

Product reviews I've seen online suggest that this flash drive is suitable for booting OS installations, and my understanding is that FAT32 is the file system architecture I want. What could be the cause of this dysfunction?

Comment: Did you follow the process outlined at http://tutorials.ubuntu.com including verifying the downloaded ISO file by checksum verification before using Rufus to generate the LiveUSB in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

First verify your hard drive partition Scheme MBR/GPT. If the scheme not match the bootable pendrive not detect for installation. So use Rufus Software for usb bootable creation with correct partition scheme. some times ubuntu bootable process need internet connection because of old image. So make sure working internet connection while creating bootable usb.